# Did any mainstream female comic character deliberately deconstruct "fanservice attire" trope?

Tags: marvel, dc

Typical DC or Marvel comics heroine would wear incredibly [fan-servicy](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Fanservice) yet absolutely impractical clothing.

The was of course deconstructed in a number of places (my favorite being the amazing "Evil, Inc" webcomic).

But was this ever deconstructed in mainstream DC or Marvel comic as well?

More specifically, I'm looking for:

- Heroine explicitly indicating that other female heros' clothing is bordering on ridiculousness.
- That same heroine choosing to wear something completely utilitarian/comfortable and explicitly rejecting the fanservice look 100%.

Comment: I'm not sure if Rogue from the X-Men would count. Aside from the fact that some of her outfits are tight, they are all explicitly modest out of necessity due to her absorption powers.

Comment: [Something like this](http://comicsbeat.com/fully-dressed-redesigns-of-superheroines/). I think the new Marvel girl (Muslim) will meet the requirement.

Comment: I know there have been numerous jokes made about Power Girl's "window" on the front of her costume.

Comment: @phantom42 - intent matters, so no. Won't count

Comment: @AnkitSharma - same as Phantom. The goal isn't to wear non-revealing cloths because it's opposite of other heroines, it's simply to follow her own cultural norms. That's NOT a deconstruction of the trope.

Comment: Also, are we only looking at characters who have either only chosen non-fanservice or have only gone into the non-fanservice direction? Some characters like Psylocke, and Rogue started out much more conservatively dressed than they later became.

Comment: @phantom42 - not sure I understand. Are you asking whether someone counts if they started out non-fanservice and then switched to fanservice? If so then yes - but again, they ONLY count if they were non-fanservice as an explicit deconstruction (e.g. not for intrinsic reason, but in opposition to every other heroine showing skin and/or wearing clearly unfunctional stuff)

Comment: On a relevant note... See [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTGh0EMmMC8) video...

Comment: I don't generally consider computer games as canon, but I had to chuckle when, in the Marvel Heroes Online MMO, the Marvel Girl character makes an amusing random quote that goes something like, "Look Emma! I can read people's minds with all my clothes on!"

Comment: This may not relate to the “fanservice attire” trope, but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20Aw9Us3o6c) video may be interesting.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the Marvel universe (Although I'm not sure how mainstream she is, as I am not completely familiar with the genre), Firestar has worn and rejected revealing clothing in favor of a more modest look (Although many would still consider it somewhat fan service, as it's skin tight).

As noted in the Wiki page for Firestar:

> Firestar demonstrated a more restrained fashion sense, refusing to wear a cleavage-baring costume designed by the Wasp. Though she is seen wearing exactly that costume in an Avengers promo poster and in some early Avengers appearances, she quickly altered the costume to be more modest, which was consistent with her personality.

The photo from wiki shows the modest costume that she favors, and it's interesting to note that the body language and choice of face wear seems to emphasize the young, somewhat shy and retiring aspect of the personality.

Regular costume

[image: Firestar image]

Here's a shot of her freaking over the Wasp designed costume. Given that later costumes are the more covering one, this would seem to corroborate it. Also remember that for much of this, Firestar was a high school age girl, which may also help explain the reticience.

[image]

Comment: Did she explicitly say that the Wasp one was too revealing as a reason to choose another one?

Comment: @DVK - Found a panel for you.

Comment: So finally one marvel heroine have own mind and avengers can't tammed her. +1 for the added picture......ohh...i already give a +1.

Answer (score 9):

Two more famous characters than Firestar have experienced both the fanservice look and rejected it on more than one occasion. Both characters are currently still in action and one of them has unfortunately returned to her fanservice appearance. One is from the Marvel Universe and has existed since the 1970s. The other is from the DC Universe and has existed since the 1940s.

### DC Universe candidate: Wonder Woman

[image]

Wonder Woman's early outfits were quite sexy and almost always exposed as much flesh as humanly possible. Over the years, several of her outfits rejected the super sexy bikini design, the shorts design on the far right and the white outfit on the far left were considered extreme departures from her standard appearance. Fan outrage eventually forced the return to the central design.

Then came the first DCNU design. A design which was supposed to empower the character and update her appearance putting her into a pair of pants for only the second time in her entire career.

[image]

Unfortunately, fans were incensed (though many did enjoy the design) more were unhappy with the flat shoes, pants and the jacket combination and when the DCNU experienced a second update via Flash Point, the outfit returned to a variation of the old design and tiny elements of the newer design.

The scalloped body armor, was the only concession to the newer design. Everything else reverted to newer versions of the old bikini design. Wider bracers, less stars on the bikini briefs, larger tiara, silver toned rather than gold. It would appear DC would rather have happy fans than a well dressed (and empowered Wonder Woman). Gloria Steinem is revolving in her grave (if she were already dead). (Steinem was a fan of Wonder Woman and her empowerment during the seventies.)

[image]

**Also see: [Does Wonder Woman Age](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/17806/2765)**

### Marvel Universe candidate: Captain Marvel (Carol Danvers)

Carol Danvers first character representation was a tribute to the legacy hero Captain Marvel (Mar-vell of Kree). Since the good Captain was unable to maintain a following it was assumed what he needed was a bit of sex appeal and Marvel Comics released Ms. Marvel. Carol Danvers was an action-oriented human female who in a complicated story found herself with analogues to Captain Marvel's powers. Her first costume however was completely fanservice.

[image]

However, when her numbers began to flag, they decided to move away from Captain Marvel's look and give her a look that was uniquely hers and would stay so for at least a decade (center image).

[image]

Her next design was not just a redesign of the costume but an increase in the overall sexiness of the character. Her breast size increased, her waist decreased, and her bikini bottoms became even more bikini-y... This design stood her in good stead until the character became entangled with Rogue and she lost her powers, presumably for good until she became the new character Binary (far right design).

After losing her Binary power she would return to her now classic sash and one piece until cultural pressures on Marvel began to influence the idea that the character should evolve once more and become the character she was designed to be all those years ago, the successor to Captain Marvel. Since at least three characters had tried and failed, Marvel decided to retool Carol Danver's look and create a new less fanserviced design. It remains to be seen whether the design will be accepted over the long haul. Signs look good.

[image]

**Also see for further information on Ms. Marvel/Captain Marvel: [Who was the first established mainstream hero type comic book character that either DC or Marvel killed off and left that way?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/31841/2765)**

Comment: The middle outfit for Wonder Woman is halfway to being a thong.

Comment: I really like the new short hair Ms/Captain Marvel look, it looks almost regal.

Comment: You lost me on the last row of images. What's the LEFT one?

Comment: Sorry, I will add some explanation in the images. The left was the return to her (now) classic sash and boots. She even got to "meet" Captain Marvel. The look on the right is her now non-fanserviced costume. The goal was to modernize her look, change her look to make her less a sex object and more the core member of the Avengers she had become. We will see if Marvel reactivates the fan-pander machine if the costume falls through.

Comment: One question - Were these different designs just evolutions in the character, or were they the result of active objections to fan service attire? OP is looking for active character objections.

Comment: They were both character oppositions and fan oppositions. For years women objected to Wonder Woman's outfit AND the character objected enough to change her outfit as well. But fanservice almost always forced the return to the classic fit.

Comment: Actually Wonder Woman's original outfit design had a lot to do with the creators' view on gender politics and sexuality. They weren't misogynistic in any way, just the opposite in fact. It had more to do with certain particular fetishes that they had incorporated into the character. See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4C25QrQaSw) for more.